# Product Catalog Diagnostics says error the events are have not detected

Tags: javascript, facebook, dynamic, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-pixel

I am trying to implemented the dynamic product ads from facebook. I have successfully implemented my facebook pixel and already have receive the events. But i still have problem in the product catalogs diagnostics. It say that my events (AddToCart, Purchase, ViewContent) are not detected. I already associate my catalogs correctly and implemented all the events:

Here is the code:

```
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
value: 10000,
currency: 'IDR',
content_ids: ['FB_product_1'],
content_type: 'product',
});


fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
value: 10000,
currency: 'IDR',
content_ids: ['FB_product_1'],
content_type: 'product',
});

fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
value: 10000,
currency: 'IDR',
content_ids: ['FB_product_1'],
content_type: 'product',
});
```

The facebook pixel also already say matched the product and the result is ok.
[image: Facebook Pixel Result]
Is there any missing step or code for associate the events with product catalogs?

Thank you.

Update:
[image: Error in Product Diagnostics]

For the data still using default facebook example data just do small modify.
[image]

Comment: where are the error? and can you show some records of product catalog?

Comment: There error is in product catalog diagnostics. I will add the screenshot.

Comment: can you confirm if the tracking products are inside the product catalog?

Comment: Yes the tracking products are matched with product catalog, today the error log is cleared by itself i do nothing. Is the product catalog diagnostics tools is not real time? And how to clear the error logs for product catalog diagnostics tools?

Comment: it usually takes within day to update. possibly you previously did not include your product in product catalog but you emitted a pixel with that products